# Execute function in current activity after onReponse() of Retrofit itself outside a service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, retrofit, android-service

I am currently working on an Android Application, and i have a problem to handle a request and execute a function just after.
The fact is my Retrofit request is in a Controller, used by a Service, and i am calling the service function inside my Activity (am i clear?).
Clearly, i have to manage one user (get and refresh access token from a webservice) and i need to be able to call my refreshToken() function and execute some code after getting and parsing the response.

This is my code :

UserActivity

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "UserActivity";
    private User user;
    private TextView textViewAccessTokenShow, textViewExpiresInShow, textViewIGPShow, textViewRefreshTokenShow;
    private LoginController loginController;
    private Wso2Service wso2Service, wso2ServiceIS;
    boolean mBounded;
    private LoginService loginService;
    private Intent mIntent;


    //Connection to LoginService
    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Service is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = false;
        loginService = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected: " );
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Service is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mBounded = true;
        LoginService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LoginService.LocalBinder) service;
        loginService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        user = loginService.getUser();
        refreshIHM();


    }
};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        mIntent = new Intent(this, LoginService.class);
        textViewAccessTokenShow = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccessTokenShow);
        textViewRefreshTokenShow = findViewById(R.id.textViewRefreshTokenShow);
        textViewExpiresInShow = findViewById(R.id.textViewExpiresInShow);
        textViewIGPShow = findViewById(R.id.textViewIGPShow);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() { //Getting my user updated outside this activity and printing his informations
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: ");
        if(mBounded == false){
            bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            user = loginService.getUser();
            refreshIHM();
        }
    }


    public void onClickRefreshToken(View view){
       //Where i have to refresh my token, and after that executing refreshIHM()

        refreshIHM();

    }


    public void refreshIHM(){
        Log.d(TAG, "refreshIHM() called");
        Log.i(TAG, "refreshIHM: "+user.toString());
        textViewExpiresInShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewAccessTokenShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewRefreshTokenShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewIGPShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        textViewAccessTokenShow.setText(user.getAccess_token());
        textViewAccessTokenShow.invalidate();
        textViewAccessTokenShow.requestLayout();

        textViewRefreshTokenShow.setText(user.getRefresh_token());
        textViewRefreshTokenShow.invalidate();
        textViewRefreshTokenShow.requestLayout();

        textViewExpiresInShow.setText(String.valueOf(user.getExpire_in()));
        textViewExpiresInShow.invalidate();
        textViewExpiresInShow.requestLayout();

        textViewIGPShow.setText(user.getId_group_parent());
        textViewIGPShow.invalidate();
        textViewIGPShow.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

LoginController, where i execute every functions about User data

```
public class LoginController {

    public static final String TAG = "LOGINSERVICE";
    private User usertemp;

    private Wso2Service wso2Service, wso2ServiceIS;

    public LoginController(){
        this.wso2Service = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Wso2Service.APIMENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(Wso2Service.class);

        this.wso2ServiceIS = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Wso2Service.ISENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(Wso2Service.class);

    }

    public User parseUserInfo(String request, User user) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(request);
            user.setAccess_token(jo.getString("access_token"));
            user.setRefresh_token(jo.getString("refresh_token"));
            user.setScope(jo.getString("scope"));
            user.setId_token(jo.getString("id_token"));
            user.setToken_type(jo.getString("token_type"));
            user.setExpire_in(jo.getInt("expires_in"));


            return user;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getUserInfo: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public User parseIdGroupParentInfo(String request, User user){
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "parseIdGroupParentInfo: "+request);
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(request);
            user.setId_group_parent(jo.getString("id_group_parent"));

            return user;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "parseIdGroupParentInfo: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void refreshToken(User user){
        this.usertemp = user;
        Log.i(TAG, "refreshToken: ");
        this.wso2Service.getTokensByRefresh("refresh_token",user.getRefresh_token(),"openid", ApiConstants.token).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //On parse la réponse
                    usertemp.setLogin_request_responseJSON(response.body());
                    parseUserInfo(response.body(), usertemp);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onLoginReady: " + usertemp.toString());
                    wso2ServiceIS.getUserInfo("Bearer "+usertemp.getAccess_token()).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.code()+response.body());
                            usertemp = parseIdGroupParentInfo(response.body(),usertemp);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ",t );
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " );
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: Code "+response.code()+" Body : "+response.body() );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ",t );
            }
        });
}

 }
```

LoginService, what i call in every activities to use the same User everytime

```
public class LoginService extends Service {
    public final String TAG = "LoginService";

    private User user;
    private LoginController loginController;
    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LoginService getServerInstance() {
            return LoginService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        this.user = (User)intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+user.toString());

        loginController = new LoginController();


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public User getUser(){
        Log.i(TAG, "getUser: ");
        return this.user;
    }

    public void regenerateByRefreshToken(){
        Log.d(TAG, "regenerateByRefreshToken: ");
        loginController.refreshToken(user);
        Log.d(TAG, "regenerateByRefreshToken: end");
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea about how to make my RefroFit function handle its response and only after executing another function inside my UI ? Or inside my regenerateByRefreshToken() function ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have any idea about how to make my RefroFit function handle its
>   response and only after executing another function inside my UI ? Or
>   inside my regenerateByRefreshToken() function ?

As per the current implementation, You can achieve this using `Callbacks`. Create two callbacks to

1. Get the `usertemp` inside service from the controller after successful execution.
2. Second callback to send the `user` object back to activity from service

So follow below steps:

a) Create callback interface

```
// create new OnUserRefresh.java
public interface OnUserRefresh{
    void onRefresh(User user);
    void onError(Throwable t);
}
```

b) Modify the controller to receive the callback reference

```
public class LoginController {

    // code...

    public void refreshToken(User user, OnUserRefresh onUserRefresh){
        this.usertemp = user;
        Log.i(TAG, "refreshToken: ");
        this.wso2Service.getTokensByRefresh("refresh_token",user.getRefresh_token(),"openid", ApiConstants.token).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //On parse la réponse
                    usertemp.setLogin_request_responseJSON(response.body());
                    parseUserInfo(response.body(), usertemp);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onLoginReady: " + usertemp.toString());
                    wso2ServiceIS.getUserInfo("Bearer "+usertemp.getAccess_token()).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.code()+response.body());
                            usertemp = parseIdGroupParentInfo(response.body(),usertemp);
                            onUserRefresh.onRefresh(usertemp);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ",t );
                            onUserRefresh.onError(t);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " );
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: Code "+response.code()+" Body : "+response.body() );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ",t );
            }
        });
    }

}
```

c) Pass callback object from service to controller

```
public class LoginService extends Service {

    /*Add interface, to be used for data passing*/

    public void regenerateByRefreshToken(OnUserRefresh onUserRefresh){
        Log.d(TAG, "regenerateByRefreshToken: ");
        loginController.refreshToken(user, new OnUserRefresh(){

            @Override
            void onRefresh(User user){
                this.user = user;
                onUserRefresh.onRefresh(user); // trigger onRefresh in client i.e. activity 
            }

            @Override
            void onError(Throwable t){
                onUserRefresh.onError(t);
                // log error etc
            }

        });
        Log.d(TAG, "regenerateByRefreshToken: end");
    }

}
```

d) Pass callback object from activity to service and implement UI updates method call

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public void onClickRefreshToken(View view){
       //Where i have to refresh my token, and after that executing refreshIHM()
        loginService.regenerateByRefreshToken(new OnUserRefresh(){

            @Override
            void onRefresh(User user){
                this.user = user;
                refreshIHM();
            }

            @Override
            void onError(Throwable t){
                // log error etc
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Note: The initial `user` reference is always `null`** as you are receiving it from intent in your service

```
this.user = (User)intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
```

but you are neither initialising any `user` object in `UserActivity` nor adding it in the `mIntent` object so you need to a `user` object with `token` and other required properties in activity for network calls.

You can optimize the flow with lambdas, Rxjava etc as well.

Comment: Thank you for all of this.
I've got two errors : The first one is in my regenerateByRefreshToken function :onUserRefresh must be declared as final in LoginController
The second : Same function, in my onRefresh(User user), Java cannot resolve symbol 'user' with my 'this.user' in UserActivity and LoginService

Comment: @Robyn.D You can make `onUserRefresh` final as it is being used inside the anonymous class and use `UserActivity.this.user = user`. Kindly note, it's just a rough presentation of the solution and I am glad that I could help, happy coding!

Comment: Yep, i modified a little bit  your code, with final keys and usertemp, and it works perfectly, and i've learned a lot! It will help a lot for the future :) Thank you again !

Comment: That's awesome and keep it up :)